# Column does not exist Error

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on an application that uses a database with three columns. The following is my create statement:

```
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_GAMES = "games";
public static final String KEY_WINS = "wins";
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
        + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" 
        + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
        + KEY_NAME  + " text not null, " 
        + KEY_GAMES + " integer, "
        + KEY_WINS  + " integer);";
```

Now, I am mapping the data in the database to a ListView by doing the following:

```
Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.getAllEntriesCursor();
    startManagingCursor(notesCursor);
String[] from = new String[]{DbAdapter.KEY_NAME, DbAdapter.KEY_WINS, DbAdapter.KEY_GAMES};
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.names, R.id.wins, R.id.games};
SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.win_games, notesCursor, from, to);
setListAdapter(notes);
```

When I run, the following error is given to me:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'wins' does not exist
```

When I shell into the emulator via command line and display the schema of the database, the following is displayed:

```
CREATE TABLE namesTable (_id integer primary key autoincrement, name text not null, games integer, wins integer);
```

So, according to that, it appears that the 'wins' column is there, but I still receive the error. Any idea why this is going on?

Comment: Please add the code you use to create `notesCursor`. Maybe you used the wrong table .

Comment: I added in the code, as requested.

Comment: The interesting part would be what is inside `getAllEntriesCursor()` - Check if this is the right database, right table and right column (in case of typos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided looks OK. So I suspect you missed smth *before*, so your DB really does not have `wins` column. Check how you create your DB.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that please? Thanks.

Comment: With some external to your app tool, could you check your db really has the `wins` column? I guess you are using Eclipse, then it is possible to extract the db file from the emulator and look at its content via some desktop SQLime viewer. Also there is a command line tool that allows to view your db - http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite .

Comment: Another ideas - do you have the only table in your app? Can you be sure you created the DB before you create list adapter?

Comment: Oh, I forgot that part, so I edited it in to the question. I did the sqlite3 command in the shell and it seems to be there. This is what I get when I do that: 

    'CREATE TABLE namesTable (_id integer primary key autoincrement, name text not null, games integer, wins integer);' ...So, it seems to be there.

Answer (score 0):

create your database like this

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
    + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" 
    + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement," 
    + KEY_NAME  + " text not null," 
    + KEY_GAMES + " integer,"
    + KEY_WINS  + " integer)";
```

Note the space separation between the column names and notice that the semicolon (;) has been removed.